# Webtrends can't read Microsoft reporting services 2008 web log

Tags: sql-server

With the change from IIS to their own web server in SSRS, we are now experiencing problems with using web trends to track our report utilization. Web trends said it was not supported, has anyone found a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know, sorry.

Usually, you "roll your own" by [mining the ExecutionLog table in the ReportServer](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3459461/MSSQL-Server-Reporting-Services-Black-Belt-Administration--Prepare-the-Execution-Log-for-Reporting.htm) database. This has lots of useful information on users, parameters, durations, errors etc.

There's far more information here than the IIS logs

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using the Native Reporting Mode.  If you switch it to Sharepoint Integrated mode I would imagine you could get some logging working again.